# Moving files to a new directory gives error: argument list too long

Tags: rhel, mv

I have

```
/path/to/dir/2018/
```

and

```
/path/to/dir/"otherfilesandfolders"
```

I need to move the `"otherfilesandfolders"` into 2018 and overwrite all

edit:

there's more than 3000 files in each subdirectory, doing

```
rsync -r -n --exclude '2018' ./* /2018/
```

gives argument list too long

Comment: `man mv` should help you. This is a really trivial task. Did you try to research this on your own beforehand?

Comment: there's more than 3000 files in each subdirectory, doing

rsync -r -n --exclude '2018' ./* /2018/

gives argument list too long

Answer (score 1):

Your `rsync` would copy, not move. Why not just move everything directly?

```
mv -f /path/to/dir/"otherfilesandfolders"/. /path/to/dir/2018/
```

Assuming that the two `/path/to/dir` elements are actually different. If not it'll be a no-op.

A real example would help provide a real answer.